# SharePoint 2010 Master Page

Tags: sharepoint

Is creating a master page for sharepoint 2010 is the same like any asp.net app?

Am not familiar with sharepoint and am required to change the master page html with a new one, also to create one aspx page that uses the master one, is there any differences compared with the normal master page?

Answer (score 2):

## Master page

A masterpage defines the structure of the page, like navigation elements that are common for the whole site.

A common technique for creating a new masterpage is copying one of the existing master pages that comes with SharePoint out of the box.

Your best bet should be to find the `v4.master` or `minimal.master` in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS` or do the editing in SharePoint Designer 2010.

## Pages

When it comes to creating new pages you have two different kinds of pages, application and site pages which both inherit from the same master page. See the [MSDN article on SharePoint Page Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979592.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

sharepoint server 2010 
Open ur sharepoint site in sharepoint designer

in sharepoint designer find the V4.master page copy this master page and rename the copied master page on that copied master page u can update/modify everthing on that master page.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to creating an aspx page that refers to the master page, the reference part remains the same for ApplicationPages, i.e. you refer the master page in the Page directive using the DynamicMasterPageFile attribute.

Defining the master page may or may not be the same depends on your requirements. However the best bet is to copy an existing master page and set the visibility of the not required SharePoint components (like ribbon) to none.